# CSS shadow in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, shadow

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#b0b0b0', Direction=135, Strength=3);
```

That is the line I have in my CSS and it gives the shadow so it is good. The problem comes when i want the same thing on the left side too. If i just add the same line again and change the line, the second line gets executed only so now there is shadow on left side but not right. How can i put it on both sides?

Note: This is only for IE, I already have it working on Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: You should try using the wonderful http://www.css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
<div style="width:240px; height:160px; padding:10px; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='Red', Direction=135, Strength=4);">
    <div style="width:240px; height:160px; padding:10px; font:bold 13pt verdana; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='Red', Direction=45, Strength=4); border:1px solid #000">
        This is the DIV content.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot put it on both sides, i had tried this earlier. Have a look at the [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the direction property.